# conditionally execute maven plugins

Tags: java, maven-2

I have some Maven plugins configured in my pom.xml. I only want to execute these plugins if the tests are being run (tests may be skipped using either `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` or `-DskipTests`).

One of these plugins is bound to the `process-classes` build lifecycle phase and the other is bound to the `pre-integration-test` phase.

Comment: I had a similar situation where I wanted to have a plug-in _(tomcat7-maven-plugin)_ available for use in local development, but not referenced in a CI build _(TeamCity, using only approved artifacts from an Artifactory repo)_. I added a `profile` element with `id=localhost-server` as suggested by @tenshi, but excluded the `activation` element. I then added an `activeProfile` element to my `settings.xml` so that it would only be active in my local environment.

Comment: Please see my post with a detailed example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/maven-command-line-arguments/33807842#33807842

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use profile with special activation conditions like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>my-test-plugins</id>

      <activation>
        <property><name>!maven.test.skip</name></property>
        <property><name>!skipTests</name></property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>

      <!-- define your plugins here -->

        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

More info you can find here:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Maven book. Really helpful to learn beyond what was asked/answered here.

Comment: How do I use IF conditions without using profile, since they aren't suitable for me? 

Basically, I have set of profiles for the whole project. For one submodule I need to choose configuration for aspect-j plugin based on the current profile. How can I do that with the proposed model, not sure...

Comment: Does this actually work? It looks like you can only have one <property> element within <activation>.

Comment: this is fine if only 1 profile needs the plugin but what if i need to run the same plugin in 2 different profiles and i dont want to duplicate the code?

Comment: Seems this answers how to conditionally activate a profile. But that was not the original question. The original question was how to conditionally activate a plugin (one of the plugins in the profile, not all of them)

Comment: Does not work: `Non-parseable POM /path/to/pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'name'`

Answer (score -3):

the last example worked only when I set also value:

```
<property>
  <name>wsdl2java</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).