# How to pass parameters to maven build using pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, parameters, build

I wanted pass maven command line parameter to POM.xml so that i can use those value for some other purpose in building purpose.

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [maven reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We can Supply parameter in different way after some search I found some useful

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>${release.artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${release.version}-${release.svm.version}</version>...
```

...

Actually in my application I need to save and supply SVN Version as parameter so i have implemented as above .

While Running build we need supply value for those parameter as follows.

```
RestProj_Bizs>mvn clean install package -Drelease.artifactId=RestAPIBiz -Drelease.version=10.6 -Drelease.svm.version=74
```

Here I am supplying

```
release.artifactId=RestAPIBiz
release.version=10.6
release.svm.version=74
```

It worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: How to pass? if executed through Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 76):

```
mvn install "-Dsomeproperty=propety value"
```

In **pom.xml**:

```
<properties>
    <someproperty> ${someproperty} </someproperty>
</properties>
```

Referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/maven-command-line-arguments) question

Comment: change "property from commandline" to ${someproperty}. Makes your code complete.

Comment: in my case (GitHub Actions) you had to remove the quotation marks

Answer (score 19):

If we have parameter like below in our POM XML

```
<version>${project.version}.${svn.version}</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

I run maven command line as follows :

```
mvn clean install package -Dproject.version=10 -Dsvn.version=1
```