# Maven: how to compile project with input parameters

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I compile my project like this:

```
mvn clean install
```

But my project has the different parameters for another servers and I need to fix it after compilation (for example `location=prod` on production server and `location=dev` on local server)
I have a pice of code in my web.xml like this:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
          classpath:/properties-config.xml
     </param-value>
</init-param>
```

I want to use the variable **location** like this :

> classpath:/${location}/properties-config.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to maven build using pom.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206013/how-to-pass-parameters-to-maven-build-using-pom-xml)

Comment: Another / our approach is: We start all our servers with a specific vm argument (the.environment=production/test/integration/etc) and in our applications, we load our configurations from /our/resource/package/-current-environment/configuration.properties. So one build will run on all servers.

Comment: Maven filtering (as suggested in [krmanish007's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27638282/3127111)) + POM properties is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass it like a VM argument: `-Dargument=value`

so run maven will be: `mvn clean install -Dlocation=dev`

it works for me, but not in web-xml.
Hope this will help u.