# What does "mvn install -D" do? And errors related

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, smartgwt

I'm in trouble with maven projects inerithed.

The projects should be built with:

```
mvn install -D module
```

and/or

```
mvn intall -D config
```

I've no more precise info about how to built the projects but these are the knowledge transfered.

If i try to build the project with "mvn install -D module" the output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for it.eng.auriga:AurigaWeb:war:1.0.5-AMA-WAVE2-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin @ line 1119, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AurigaWeb 1.0.5-AMA-WAVE2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/2.7.0/gwt-maven-plugin-2.7.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.079 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-26T13:14:13+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:2.7.0: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:pom:2.7.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

while if I try to build the project with "mvn intall -D config" then the output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for it.eng.auriga:AurigaWeb:war:1.0.5-AMA-WAVE2-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin @ line 1119, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AurigaWeb 1.0.5-AMA-WAVE2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.105 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-26T13:19:43+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "intall". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Then in both cases the build fails.

Looking at the output of "mvn install -D module", the Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0 is in the right path of local maven repository but it fails anyway.

Looking at the output of "mvn install -D config" instead, seems that something is missing.

Someone know how these options works?

I have also missing artifacts errors in pom.xml also if the plugin are in the right path of local maven repository:

```
Missing artifact com.isomorphic.smartgwt.lgpl:smartgwt-skins:jar:12.0-p20190920
Missing artifact it.eng.utility:SezioneCache:jar:1.0.3
Missing artifact javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3
```

Someone know how I can remove these errors?

Eclipse is Oxygen.
Java version is 1.8 on OS.
JDK compliance is 1.7.
Installed JRE is 1.7.

Comment: In the second one you misspelled `install` as `intall`

Comment: The option `-D` defines properties which I doubt is correct. If that's really the need you should remove the space between `module` and `-D` like this: `mvn -Dmodule install`?

Comment: Also I've seen `rg/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version` that looks like you are using JDK7 where you need to define `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3` because central only allows TLSv1.3 apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade your JDK version... and use `--release`option to produce JDK 7 compatible code. Also your Eclipse version really out of date...Also there are a number of maven plugins in the meantime which require JDK8 at minimum... (even JDK8 is of 2014!)

Comment: Yes @greg-449, my mistake. Of course is install.

Comment: @khmarbaise the output of "mvn -Dmodule install" is the same. Always the same error.
Moreover, I've rollback eclipse from 2020-06 to oxygen and jdk from 17 to 1.8 and at least to 1.7 in order to resolve a lot of error. The source code is too old and I think that it was written with 1.7. Anyway I will try again with eclipse 2020-06 and jdk1.8.

Comment: Do you possibly mean 'mvn install -P module' or 'mvn install -P config'? '-P' stands for Maven Profile.

Comment: @MichaelKatt I've tested it but in both cases the output is:
"[WARNING] The requested profile "module" could not be activated because it does not exist."
or
"[WARNING] The requested profile "config" could not be activated because it does not exist."
and then [ERROR].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ERROR] in the build output and searching I've found this:

[How to pass parameters to maven build using pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206013/how-to-pass-parameters-to-maven-build-using-pom-xml)

that suggest to me how to complete the command.

Then I passed these two variables with -D options:

mvn clean install -Dmodule=auriga -Dconfig=AMA_SVIL

and than the BUILD SUCCESS!