# Maven command line argument vs pom property

Tags: maven, properties, command-line-arguments, pom.xml

I've defined a property in my pom. I can also define it as a command line argument. If I make so, will my property be overridden OR conjugated OR property in pom has a higher priority and a command line argument has no effect?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you run it with command-line args, it will override the property-values that are in the pom.xml.

for example, if I have a dependency in my pom:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

...

```
 <properties>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
 </properties>
```

and then, if I run command:

```
mvn clean install -Dmockito.version=1111
```

maven will search for version 1111 (which does not exist, of course). As you say - **command line has a higher priority**.

Comment: in addition, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/maven-command-line-arguments