# Share common configuration across profiles in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

We have a parent POM for our project which provides lot of configuration. In our project, we need to provide some more configuration if a certain profile is activated. We currently do it this way

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prof1</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.somegroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <someConfig combine.children="append">
                                <param>paramCommon</param>
                                <param>paramProf1</param>
                            </someConfig>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prof2</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.somegroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <someConfig combine.children="append">
                                <param>paramCommon</param>
                                <param>paramProf2</param>
                            </someConfig>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prof3</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.somegroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <someConfig combine.children="append">
                                <param>paramCommon</param>
                                <param>paramProf3</param>
                            </someConfig>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prof4</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.somegroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <someConfig combine.children="append">
                                <param>paramCommon</param>
                                <param>paramProf4</param>
                            </someConfig>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The problem here is we repeat the whole `build` everywhere. I would want to avoid that. I want to pass `paramProfX` through a property. The plugin configuration here cannot be moved out of profiles as it must be included if and only if one of the four profiles is activated otherwise not.

Here, I can move `paramCommon` and the rest of the `build` tag in another profile with `paramProfX` to be a property and pass `paramProfX` through some other profile as a property. But, in that case I may need to activate both profiles simultaneously which I don't want to do as activating only one of the four profiles will do nothing and hence would be misleading.

What is the best way to achieve this if I would like to activate only one profile at a time?

Comment: You could pass the paramProfX [property on the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515282/3284624)

Comment: @D.B. I don't want to do that