# Move default value of pom.xml property to external file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In my spring project, the root `pom.xml` contain some property

```
<properties>
    <rev>3.0</rev>
    <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>
</properties>
```

It's a multi-module project. These properties are being used in all child `pom.xml` file throughout the whole project. The `pom.xml` in child module use these properties like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-root</artifactId>
    <version>${rev}${changelist}</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

I can modify the default value of that property in terminal by `mvn test -Dchangelist=-release` 
Now, what I want to do is move the default value of those properties to an external file. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven ? **Where** are the rev and changelist properties used??

Comment: @RC. I've updated my question. rev and changelist are being used in all child pom.

Comment: You can smiply use the `.mvn/maven.config` for that.

Comment: @khmarbaise Do you please describe the process a little more (with appropriate example)?

Comment: Please read the release notes http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html

Comment: then see the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm sure it'll work for me. I've another query. Please don't mind. I don't find any `maven.config` file in my .mvn directory. Do I need to create one?

Comment: If you don't have a `.mvn` directory than sure you need to create it...

Comment: Thanks, @khmarbaise . My problem solved.