# How to pass parameter into pom.xml as a maven goal to run tests in parallel?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, junit5

I need to run my tests in parallel (JUnit5), but I don't now how to pass parameter into pom.xml as a maven goal.

For this moment I have such configuration for maven-surefire-plugin in my pom.xml, but I would like to pass `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true` as a maven goal, for example `"parallel=true"`.

```
          <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=dynamic
                            junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

It can be useful to chose when to run tests in parallel, when to run them in the same thread.

How I can do it? Could you please help me?

Comment: Why from command line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing command line arguments from Maven as properties in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml)

Comment: Please use one of the answers in the above question that I've commented.

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry, probably I have explained bad. It seems, it will be correctly to say "as a maven goal"

Comment: Your comment confuses me much more ? Please explain in detail what you like to do and why you like to do and what kind of problem you like to solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.

In properties of `pom.xml` I set this:

```
<properties>
   ...
   <parallel>false</parallel>
</properties>
```

Next, in plugin configuration I will set this:

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = ${parallel}
                            ...
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now I can run my test this way `mvn -Dparallel=true test`and set `true`when I want my tests run in parallel or `false` when I want they run in the same thread