# An Ant BuildException has occured: HTTP Authorization failure

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am using `maven-antrun-plugin` to download jre. I can download if my configuration is

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>artifactory-jre</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <!-- download file -->
                                <get src="${download.url}/${download.file}${download.filePostfix}"
                                     dest="${project.build.directory}/${download.file}${download.filePostfix}"
                                     verbose="true"
                                     usetimestamp="true"
                                     username="user"
                                     password="password123"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but I do not wants to provide the `username` and `password` in `pom` file, I tried adding server entry in the `settings.xml` like

```
   <server>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password123</password>
      <id>artifactory-jre</id>
    </server>
```

but I am getting following exception.

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (artifactory-jre) on project name.abuchen.zulu.jre.win32.x86_64: An Ant BuildException has occured: HTTP Authorization failure
[ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 4:315 in C:\Users\Downloads\bundled-jre-master\bundled-jre-master\bundles\name.abuchen.zulu.jre.win32.x86_64\ta
rget\antrun\build-main.xml**

How can I supply username and password in Ant without being provided in pom file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml/7515282

Answer (score 0):

For the solution. I created property in `setting.xml` and used that in `pom.xml`

my setting.xml looks like

```
<properties>
<user>user_name</user>
<password>my_password</password>
</properties>
```

in `pom.xml` I used this property as any other property.