# Add parameter to TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, pom.xml

I was given the task to add to "Teamcity" the ability to change the number of threads in "pom.xml so that the tests are performed either in single thread or more. I did not find any information.So i think i should add parameters to change  3 value.

```
<profile>
    <id>#######</id>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <excludes>
```

Comment: just define maven property and pass it through the commandline from teams. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml