# unable to run test in maven+cucumber

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

While running my cucumber test using maven ,i am getting build success but none of the tests are running . I have attached :

- POM dependencies versions
- Result
- Structure of the project
- Runner class

I have followed below work around :

1. already checked the version compatibility of dependencies guess that is fine
2. deleted M2 repositories and build the project again
3. Tried changing the project structure and added naming convention
   "Test" with java files.

```
    T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running cucumberOptions.TestRunnerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.026 s - in cucumberOptions.TestRunnerTest
[INFO] Running pages.baseTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in pages.baseTest
[INFO] Running pages.GenericUtilsTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in pages.GenericUtilsTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>1.1.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies> 
<build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin> 
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
          <configuration>

          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

```
[updated structure and result][2]

[updated structure][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Y79.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fqsL.jpg
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml

Comment: I didn't find my answer in that thread .  i guess that talks about some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure does not follow the maven conventions. All test classes (ending with `.java`) should go under `src/test/java` and test resources (ending with `.feature`) under `src/test/resources`.

Because your feature files are not the in the right place they're not picked up by Cucumber.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

You may also want to follow the 10-minute Cucumber tutorial so you have a working Cucumber project before adding on Selenium.

https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: Hey, i made the changes to the structure but still the issue exists. Have added the updated result and the structure .

Comment: Doesn't look like it. It should be `src/test/resources` not `src/main/resources`. And you're better of following the tutorials.

Comment: Thanks made the changes but still the problem persists :(