# io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am facing issue with - io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration issue when upgrading Spring , Gradle

```
Gradle - 7.6 , Spring boot - 3.0.2, Intellij - 2022.3.2, Java - 17,
```

**build.gradle**

```
 testImplementation"io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:7.11.1 
 testImplementation"io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.11.1"
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

Please note that this set was working before the upgrade.  I am really not sure what is missing.

**EndToEndTestsCoverage:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = ["com.xxx.endToEndTests.steps"],
        features = ["classpath:com/xxx/endToEndTests/features"])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class EndToEndTestsCoverage
```

**Config:**

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = [(com.xxx.Application::class)], webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

Comment: Projects typically include a CHANGELOG and release notes in their source code. These inform you about new features and breaking changes. Have you tried reading those?

Comment: This issue is resolved now by adding config path to glue as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562903/is-additional-context-configuration-required-when-upgrading-cucumber-jvm-from-ve.  Now facing "Undefined Scenarios" issue even though the feature and step file is linked.

Comment: Your IDE and Cucumber are two independent systems. Just because one can understand, the other may not. So maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803971/unable-to-run-test-in-mavencucumber/60813339#60813339

Comment: But probably you should ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This issue is fixed now.  Dependency files also need to be aligned.  I was using io.cucumber but importing from cucumber.java.   Changed the import also from io.cucumber.