# How to pass a command line argument in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing a little Java project with Maven, so I want to pass (for example) `/blabla/config.json` as command line argument to read info but I don't know how. I think that maybe use **properties** but I'm not nothing sure.

Comment: during `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Really?, let me check it out. Do you have a example or something? thank you so much!

Comment: check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml