# Loading files from the resources folder from a class in a separate Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a Maven library that needs to access resources in the project it is used in. Currently, accessing these resources only works if I specify the absolute path, which is not ideal. I would like to use the relative path, but so far I have had no success with it.
I use java 17, javafx and have a module-info accordingly. (In the project and in the library)

Do I have to release the resources folder for the library somehow?

This is the code in the library:

```
String path = "/me/test/test.xml";
getClass().getResource(path)
```

If I use the code directly in the project, it works.
I also tried to use getResourceAsStream, same problem.

Comment: this for me looks like you are misunderstanding some concepts. When you have a library, it's functionality should be used. So the library does not need to access resources from the using project. Rather you should have to call the functionality with i.e. a path to the resource as a parameter. 
If you really need to set values into the dependency, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml

Comment: Files in the `resources` folder in Maven are embedded in the produced JAR and available in the classpath when you use this JAR.

Comment: I don't understand what case works and what case doesn't? Could you clarify with concrete code? You're also mentioning an absolute vs. Relative path: can you clarify that as well?

Comment: My library needs direct access to the resource folder of the project, as the xml files it contains have to be read out.  In this case, I would like to avoid passing the whole thing as a parameter to the library (if this is possible at all)

I am trying to get access to the resources folder of the project in which this maven dependency is used within my library. When I execute getResource(path) in the library, I do not get the resource. However, if I execute the exact same code directly in the project, the whole thing works.

Comment: You mention having a module-info file. In modules, resources within packages are encapsulated by default. If you want other modules to be able to read the resource, either `opens` the package or pass the other module a `URL` / `InputStream` to the resource instead. And I'm not sure I understand your issue with absolute versus relative paths. The relative path is always relative to the package of the class you called `getResource` on. If the resource is not relative to that package, then a relative path cannot be used (note `..` is not supported).

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your question:

1. Understanding of resources with Maven
2. Circular dependency between main project and dependency (lib)

## 1. Understanding of resources with Maven

External files are not loaded from the *resources/* folder at runtime, but Maven packages them into the bundled artifact. (Usually a JAR file, but this could be changed. For simplicity I just use "JAR file" for the rest of the answer instead of "bundled artifact".)

Maven does this in a way you can access your resources (files) that you initially put into your *resources/* folder as if they were in the "root" of your JAR file. So if you create subfolders in *resources/* those subfolders are also created or used in your JAR file - and they can be accessed there with a path relative to the *resources/* folder in your source project. Never use absolute paths to access resources please.

## 2. Circular dependency

It seems that you build a circular dependency here:

Your main project depends on an independent library that depends on the resource file of your project. So the library is no longer independent of your project.

To resolve this, you have three options:

- Move the resource to your library - eventually provide it to the users of the lib (your main project)
- Read the resource in your main project (as `InputStream`, as URL in object or string form or even as the bytes the file contains) and provided it with an appropriate function to the lib (you call the lib with the parameter). This is only possible if the lib already provides the option to pass such a parameter in or you can add that to the lib.
- Merge lib and main project into the main project as they are not independent. You also could just merge the part of the lib that needs the main projects resource, if this is extractable easily from the lib.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a circular dependency. You can have a library that expects its user to have a file in the classpath and the library may want to access that file directly without having it provided via InpuStream or another ref. Think of a logging library that reads a logging.properties defined in theain project.