Git branch name in pom.xml properties
I am trying to use git branch name in pom.xml properties for sonar scan.
<properties> `
<sonar.branch.name>${branch.name}</sonar.branch.name>`
</properties>

for this i am trying to use exec-maven-plugin and the plugin configuration is shown below
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>get-git-branch-name</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>git</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>rev-parse</argument>
                                    <argument>--abbrev-ref</argument>
                                    <argument>HEAD</argument>
                                </arguments>
                                <outputProperty>branch.name</outputProperty>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

i am getting an error as  Parameter 'outputProperty' is unknown for plugin 'exec-maven-plugin:3.3.0:exec (get-git-branch-name)' .
how to get the output of the execution in variable so that it can be used in properties? or any other alternative way to get git branch name in <sonar.branch.name>

Bit curious why you need the branch to be resolved using maven. If you want to use sonar in a build pipeline I would recommend using the build pipeline to fetch the current branch and pass it as a parameter. Eg: mvn install -DbranchName=my-branch-name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml for ref

You can try buildnumber-maven-plugin which can set a property: ${scmBranch}
