# How to ignore a particular goal defined inside pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl

I am defining a goal inside my pom.xml. There is a condition when I want the goal not to be executed. My pom.xml is:

```
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>

            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
              <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/myWsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
              <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
             <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
              <packageName>com.example.client</packageName>
              <flattenFiles>true</flattenFiles> 
              <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <action>
                <ignore/>
            </action>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I tried using  tag but it didnt work.

How can I make my pom.xml to skip this particular goal?

Comment: Have you thought about using profiles?

Comment: No. I am trying this for the first time. So, unaware about certain things. Can you plz help me out with this?

Comment: BTW: What i missed. Why are defining the output directory to be the `src` folder which is usually under version control. Which does not make sense. Apart from that the tag `<action>` and `<ignore/>` do not belong there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a profile like this:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>my-profile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/myWsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                                <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                                <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                                <packageName>com.example.client</packageName>
                                <flattenFiles>true</flattenFiles>
                                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This can be activated in relationship with maven like this:

```
mvn -Pmy-profile clean package
```

If you don't specify the `-Pmy-profile` the execution of the plugin will not executed.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet so I'm posting this as an answer)

As khmarbaise said, you should try using profiles for this.

Take a look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443097/conditionally-execute-maven-plugins).