# If I run a plugin from the command line at the root pom, what does it do when traversing modules?

Tags: java, scala, maven, gatling

I'm trying to use the plugin:  http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.1/extensions/maven_plugin.html

I'm trying to run this command at the root pom:

```
mvn package gatling:execute
```

This multi module project only has this plugin defined in one child pom like so:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                    <arg>-feature</arg>
                    <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when I run this command at the root, it gives this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building root-pom 2.5.210-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:2.1.7:execute (default-cli) @ root-pom ---
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find the jar matching (.*scala-library.*\.jar)$
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$$anonfun$jarMatching$1$2.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:88)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$$anonfun$jarMatching$1$2.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:88)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.jarMatching$1(ZincCompiler.scala:88)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.setupZincCompiler(ZincCompiler.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:106)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:35)
    at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

This is not a scala project, so this is definitely related to the plugin.  Running `mvn package` without `gatling:execute` works fine.

I do not know enough about maven to be able to troubleshoot this problem because I can't really tell what maven is trying to do here.  *If it is trying to run gatling at the root, why?*  That plugin is not defined in the root pom anywhere.  My question is:

1. When you run a plugin at the root of a multi-module project, how does it traverse my project, look for plugins and run them?  I'm asking this question abstractly.  You don't have to answer in terms of gatling.  I just want to understand maven plugins better.
2. How do I troubleshoot this issue?  I think I could add scala to the root pom, but since it would be the first dependency at that level, it seems like it's the wrong approach.

   I could also `cd` into the one child pom that has this plugin and run the command there, but that means I'll only be running `package` on a piece of the project.  Ideally I'd like to run `package` on the whole project before I run the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running maven with a plugin goal like that will run that goal for all project modules, the same as `mvn install` will install each module. You don't have to define the plugin anywhere - if you specify it on the commandline, it is run.

You correctly bound the execution of that plugin to one or more lifecycle phases, in this case `process-resources` and `process-test-resources`. If you run `mvn compile`, the the `process-resources` phase will be executed and the `add-sources` and `compile` goals will be run for the gatling plugin. Similarly, running `mvn test` (which is also run when you `mvn install`) will run the `testCompile` goal of the gatling plugin.

What you'll want to do is to also bind the `execute` goal as is exemplified 
on the [page you linked](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.1/extensions/maven_plugin.html). If you want everyting `package`d first, bind it to the
[integration test phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html):

```
<execution>
  <phase>integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>execute</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
     ....
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Note that `integration-test` comes *after* `package` (and somewhere before `install`), so to run it, execute `mvn integration-test` or `mvn install`.

Comment: It depends on the plugin. If it is a core plugin, it'll be located using some [default groupId's](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html). You can also specify any random maven plugin to run on the commandline using `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal` (or something very close to that syntax).

Comment: That `execute` tip is very helpful.  But I want this plugin to be run *after* package, not during.  I also want to run package everywhere else first.  What technique can I use for that?

Comment: Updated the answer: there's an integration-test phase just for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry I communicated poorly.  I meant I only want to run this plugin after package *sometimes*, not every time.  I don't want this to be triggered after every `package`, I want to explicitly tell it to run.

Comment: Ah. In that case you can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443097/conditionally-execute-maven-plugins#5443207) for an example.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, there's also [`-Dgatling.skip=true`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/1063); using profiles you can set that to true by default using a `<property>` and override the value with a profile. But defining the plugin within a profile is more portable. Good luck!